# Implementing more than one autocomplete on slickgrid by changing SlickGridEditor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, slickgrid

I have a slick grid data columns and one field has a country autocomplete in the editor type field. Here is the grid set up

```
var columns =[ { id: "CountryOfOrigin", name: "Country Of Mfg.", field: "CountryOfOrigin", minWidth: 120, editor: Slick.Editors.Auto }, ];
```

There are also other fields left out of code listing for brevity. I changed my
SlickGridEditor.js to incorporate the country autocomplete source table as follows

```
var availableTags = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", ];
```

And I changed the AutoCompleteEditor function in the SlickGridEditor.js as follows

```
       function AutoCompleteEditor(args) {
    var $input;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;
    var calendarOpen = false;

    this.init = function () {
        $input = $("<INPUT id='tags' class='editor-text' />");
        $input.appendTo(args.container);
        $input.focus().select();
        $input.bind("keydown.nav", function (e) {
            if ((e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.UP ||
                 e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER)
              && $('ul.ui-autocomplete').is(':visible')) e.stopPropagation();

            if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT)
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
        minLength: 3,

        $input.autocomplete({
            source: availableTags


        });
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
        $input.autocomplete("destroy");
    };

    this.focus = function () {
        $input.focus();
    };
```

Now I need to add autocomplete to another field in the grid named region that has a list of regions I want autocompleted like 
Africa, Asia, Central America,Eastern Europe,European Union,Middle East,North America, Oceania, South America, The Caribbean

Can I deploy multiple autocompletes on the same grid and how would I do that?
Thanks so much in advance.